# Error al conectar app Android con Bd Sql Server

Tags: android-studio, sql-server

Tengo el siguiente codigo el cual siempre entra al método onLoginFailed(), y me tira este error "android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException:: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException".

Quisiera que alguien fuera tan amable de mirar mi código y apoyarme en que estoy fallando ya que recién empiezo con Android.

```html
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Connection connection=null;
    String ip="xxx.xxx.0.10/mydata";
    String classs="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver";
    String db="Mybd";
    String user="myuser";
    String pass="mypass";
    String cn;

    private static final String TAG = "";
    EditText _user, _pass;
    Button _singin;
    conexion con;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
      _user=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
      _pass=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
      _singin=(Button) findViewById(R.id.login);

      _singin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
      {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v)
          {
              switch (v.getId())
              {
                  case R.id.login:
                    if(login()){
                        onLoginSuccess();
                    }
                    else{
                        onLoginFailed();
                    }
                  break;
              }
          }
      });
  }

    public Connection conexion ()
    {
        try
        {
            Class.forName(classs);
            cn="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://"+ip+";databaseName="+db+";user="+user+";password="+pass+";";
            connection= DriverManager.getConnection(cn);
            Log.i("paso1","Conexion OK");
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            Log.e("error1 : ", e.getMessage());
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            Log.e("error2 : ", e.getMessage());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.e(""+ex.toString()+ ": ", ex.toString());
        }
        return connection;
    }


    public boolean login()
    {
        String datosConsultado = "";
        try
        {
            Connection connect = conexion();
            if(connect!=null)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else{
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }
    }

    private void onLoginFailed() {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No conectado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        _singin.setEnabled(true);
    }

    private void onLoginSuccess() {
        Intent intent =new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        LoginActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Las aplicaciones móviles se conectan a servicios web que son los que se comunican con las bases de datos.

Comment: @fredyfx sabras de algun curso o tutorial que pueda guiarme?, gracias

Comment: he buscado mucho y en todos veo "lo mismo"

Comment: Vamos al chat y te explico todos los motivos

Comment: @fredyfx okay gracias